# Undefined $load property error after upgrading CodeIgniter 1.7 to 2.1

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, undefined

Why I get this error after upgrading CodeIgniter from v1.7 to v2.1?

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Site::$load

Filename: libraries/Website.php

Line Number: 25

Fatal error: Call to a member function library() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\travel\application\libraries\Website.php on line 25
```

The library application/library/website

```
class Website extends CI_Controller {

    public static $current_city;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->load->library('language'); // line 25
        $this->language->loadLanguage();
        $this->load_main_lang_file();
        $this->load_visitor_geographical_data();
        $this->load->library('bread_crumb');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to call `__construct` method of `CI_Controller` class:

```
public function __construct()
{
    // Call CI_Controller construct method first.
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->library('language'); // line 25
    $this->language->loadLanguage();
    $this->load_main_lang_file();
    $this->load_visitor_geographical_data();
    $this->load->library('bread_crumb');
}
```

**Note:** If you're creating a Controller, it should be placed in `application/controllers/`, not in `application/libraries/`.

If the child (inheritor) class has a constructor, the parent constructor won't be called, because you'll override parent's constructor with the child one, unless you explicitly call parent's constructor using `parent::__construct();`. That's the concept of **[Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming)** in [object-oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)

If you don't call `parent::__construct();` when the application controller is initializing, you'll lose [`Loader` and `Core`](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/core/Controller.php#L37-L54) class and `$this->load` would never works.

Using `parent::__construct();` is needed only if you want to declare `__construct()` method in your Controller which it will override the parent's one.

That's true for models as well, but using `parent::__construct();` in your model just logs a debug message `Model Class Initialized`, So if you need to know when Model is initialized *(in logs)*, keep using that, If not, ignore it.