# Understanding how CodeIgniter works

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am totally newbie to codeigniter.Now i am getting a error which says

`CI_Controller::CI_Controller() in D:\wamp\www\codeigniter\application\controllers\hello.php on line 8`.

I also want you to explain why we need to require parent to be there on that line. If you explain the flow of program just clearly it will be a great help.

```
<?php
class Hello extends CI_Controller
{
 var $name;
 var $color;
   function Hello()
   { 
     parent::CI_Controller();
     $this->name="andy";
     $this->color="red";
   }
   function you()
   {
    $data['name']=$this->name;
    $data['color']=$this->color;
    $this->load_>view("you_view",$data);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Note that you need to use `parent::__construct();` if you're overriding the `__construct()` method. This would be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18320446/undefined-load-property-error-after-upgrading-codeigniter-1-7-to-2-1/18321751#18321751

Answer (score 0):

the `construct` has to be implemented like this

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->data=array(
       'name'=>'andy'
       'color'=>'red'
       );
    }

    function you(){
    $this->load_>view("you_view",$this->data);
   }
```